# position the radio box to the left side of its label

Tags: html, css

I want to put the radio box at the right of the each label:

```css
.choices .choices-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.choices .item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.choices .checkbox,
.choices .radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.choices .checkbox + label,
.choices .radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
  transition: color 0.15s ease;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before,
.choices .radio + label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #dddd;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, border 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label::before,
.choices .radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label,
.choices .radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}
.choices .checkbox + label {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAvklEQVRIS+2U0Q3CMAwFzxuwCYwAEzECdAM2ghHoJmxgZJRIUWgTh9C/9Du9q59fKmz8yMZ8hqCa8IjoE5Gq7oCziEx5Zt0RBfgdOACTiFxTSZcgg8/AUURefxF44Cb6aQIvvChQVcvylo/cAl8VBPgFeAKnKGmFlwRWuwewj5KwuNiWxYUuXevVHYSvTSX2vlXRDa8uOZPY+SZ4VZDcUpvEnq+e1/52rpqGScgbVYO7JvBASmdcE/RIhqCa3ht9IVAZxGa2wAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::before {
  border-color: #7579e7;
  background: #7579e7;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.choices .radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.choices .radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}
.choices .radio:checked + label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 7px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-choice">

    <h1 class="question">سوال در اینجا رار می گیرد؟</h1>

    <form class="choices">
      <ul class="choices-list">
         <li class="item">
            <label for="children">children</label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="children">
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="teen">
            <label for="teen">teen</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="adult">
            <label for="adult">adult</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="aduflt">
            <label for="aduflt">adult</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </form>

  </div>
```

I tried to put the label before the input tag to achieve this but the radio box disappeared!!!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align them all to the same amount, use `left: <value>`.

```css
.choices .choices-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.choices .item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.choices .checkbox,
.choices .radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.choices .checkbox + label,
.choices .radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
  transition: color 0.15s ease;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before,
.choices .radio + label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(35px, -50%);
  background: #dddd;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, border 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label::before,
.choices .radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label,
.choices .radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}
.choices .checkbox + label {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAvklEQVRIS+2U0Q3CMAwFzxuwCYwAEzECdAM2ghHoJmxgZJRIUWgTh9C/9Du9q59fKmz8yMZ8hqCa8IjoE5Gq7oCziEx5Zt0RBfgdOACTiFxTSZcgg8/AUURefxF44Cb6aQIvvChQVcvylo/cAl8VBPgFeAKnKGmFlwRWuwewj5KwuNiWxYUuXevVHYSvTSX2vlXRDa8uOZPY+SZ4VZDcUpvEnq+e1/52rpqGScgbVYO7JvBASmdcE/RIhqCa3ht9IVAZxGa2wAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::before {
  border-color: #7579e7;
  background: #7579e7;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.choices .radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.choices .radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}
.choices .radio:checked + label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 7px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-choice">

    <h1 class="question">سوال در اینجا رار می گیرد؟</h1>

    <form class="choices">
      <ul class="choices-list">
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="children">
            <label for="children">children</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="teen">
            <label for="teen">teen</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="adult">
            <label for="adult">adult</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="aduflt">
            <label for="aduflt">adult</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </form>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already using absolute positioning...so replace its left property with right.
If you want them to align together, you could use a flexbox row or you could set relative on the container.

```css
.choices .choices-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.choices .item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.choices .checkbox,
.choices .radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.choices .checkbox + label,
.choices .radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
  transition: color 0.15s ease;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before,
.choices .radio + label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(35px, -50%);
  background: #dddd;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, border 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label::before,
.choices .radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label,
.choices .radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}
.choices .checkbox + label {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAvklEQVRIS+2U0Q3CMAwFzxuwCYwAEzECdAM2ghHoJmxgZJRIUWgTh9C/9Du9q59fKmz8yMZ8hqCa8IjoE5Gq7oCziEx5Zt0RBfgdOACTiFxTSZcgg8/AUURefxF44Cb6aQIvvChQVcvylo/cAl8VBPgFeAKnKGmFlwRWuwewj5KwuNiWxYUuXevVHYSvTSX2vlXRDa8uOZPY+SZ4VZDcUpvEnq+e1/52rpqGScgbVYO7JvBASmdcE/RIhqCa3ht9IVAZxGa2wAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::before {
  border-color: #7579e7;
  background: #7579e7;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.choices .radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.choices .radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}
.choices .radio:checked + label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 7px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-choice">

    <h1 class="question">سوال در اینجا رار می گیرد؟</h1>

    <form class="choices">
      <ul class="choices-list">
         <li class="item">
            <label for="children">children</label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="children">
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="teen">
            <label for="teen">teen</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="adult">
            <label for="adult">adult</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="aduflt">
            <label for="aduflt">adult</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: hmmmm, I think this is not the best approach, it just pushes the element and there is not correct alignment... I want the radio boxes to be in line...

Comment: What do you mean with 'in line' – all in one row or like your own example in column?

Comment: I mean each check box has different position vertically...

Comment: I mentioned that you can get it to align by setting the parent to a relative position with a fixed width

Comment: Nevermind, I am mistaken - as we need a relative for the parent. Check my new solution, which uses a static `left` position instead. Whilst this isn't responsive, it does work.

Comment: I would personally recommend remaking the radio as an actual element instead of a pseudoselector, which will allow us to leverage things like CSS grid and Flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to replace **left: 0** with **right: -32px** for 'label::before'.
Then you can delete the padding:

```
.choices .radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
```

Working example:

```css
.choices .choices-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.choices .item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.choices .checkbox,
.choices .radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.choices .checkbox + label,
.choices .radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
  transition: color 0.15s ease;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before,
.choices .radio + label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #dddd;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, border 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label::before,
.choices .radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.choices .checkbox:hover + label,
.choices .radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}
.choices .checkbox + label {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.choices .checkbox + label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAvklEQVRIS+2U0Q3CMAwFzxuwCYwAEzECdAM2ghHoJmxgZJRIUWgTh9C/9Du9q59fKmz8yMZ8hqCa8IjoE5Gq7oCziEx5Zt0RBfgdOACTiFxTSZcgg8/AUURefxF44Cb6aQIvvChQVcvylo/cAl8VBPgFeAKnKGmFlwRWuwewj5KwuNiWxYUuXevVHYSvTSX2vlXRDa8uOZPY+SZ4VZDcUpvEnq+e1/52rpqGScgbVYO7JvBASmdcE/RIhqCa3ht9IVAZxGa2wAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::before {
  border-color: #7579e7;
  background: #7579e7;
}
.choices .checkbox:checked + label::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.choices .radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}
.choices .radio:checked + label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 7px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-choice">

    <h1 class="question">سوال در اینجا رار می گیرد؟</h1>

    <form class="choices">
      <ul class="choices-list">
         <li class="item">
            <label for="children">children</label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="children">
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="teen">
            <label for="teen">teen</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="adult">
            <label for="adult">adult</label>
         </li>
         <li class="item">
            <input type="radio" name="age" class="radio" id="aduflt">
            <label for="aduflt">adult</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </form>

</div>
```